# By given equation, finding orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find the orthogonal projection of line with direction vector $u = ( 1 , 2 , 0 )$ onto the plane
described by equation $-3x - 2y + 2z = -2$

i have tried to search `orthogonal projection of line onto the plane` but couldn't find an example with plane equation, but matrix or $(a,b,c)$ 
 if it were give by matrix i think i can find but this 'equation' makes me confusing. 
 any plane equation and direction vector example? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane has normal vector $n=(-3, - 2 , 2)$. You first find the projection of $u$ on $n$, then use $u$ minus it to get the direction of the projection line on the plane.

Comment: sorry im bloody beginner. That =-2 doesn't change anything ?

Comment: @Andy In order to determine a plane, you need a normal direction and a point. Normal direction is given by the first three coefficients while the fourth one determines whether the plane can pass through a given point. In your case, you need $-2$ to determine the intersection point of the line and the plane

Comment: ok here im going: $Proj_n U = u*n/|n*n| times (-3,-2,2) = 7/17(-3,-2,2)$ is it right?

Comment: @Andy You also need to use $u$ to minus it. Draw a picture and you will see it.

Comment: and $Proj_p U = U- Proj_n U$ and its $(38/17,48/17,14/17)$ is this right ?

Comment: which means i didn't use that $= -2$ to find orthogonal projection

Comment: @Andy the expression is correct. I don't hand a pen nearby so I may not be able to help you verify your calculation result.